# CSS circles with text inline

Tags: css, geometry, inline

I'm trying to make a couple of css circles with text inside in one line. When I use circle class to img, circles are inline, but I cannot add any text. When I use circle class to div, I can add text, but they don't display inline, even when I add display:inline to circle class.

CSS

```
        img.galeria{
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 3px;
        border-color: yellow;
        width: 12%;
        height: 75.825%;
        border-radius: 50%;
        -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
        -moz-border-radius: 50%;
        box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0, .8);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0, .8);
        margin-right: 2%;
    }
```

HTML for the first option (img)

```
<a href="abecadlo/"><img class="galeria" src="../images/backgrounds/light-blue.png"/></a>
```

HTML for the second option (div)

```
<a href="abecadlo/"><div class="galeria"/>text</a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle with the code you're trying please. Also, you're missing a closing div tag before your closing a tag in option 2.

Answer (score 4):

In your style, replace display: inline; with display:inline-block;. It worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

[**Try this**](http://jsfiddle.net/qgy26/)

```
.galeria {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: yellow;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
    background:url('...imgsrc.jpg');
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say that you tried display: inline, but it isn't in your code.

If you try it, it works

```
.galeria{
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 3px;
     border-color: yellow;
     width: 12%;
     height: 75.825%;
     border-radius: 50%;
     box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0, .8);
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0, .8);
     margin-right: 2%;
     display: inline;
 }
```

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/8BPyS/)